# if (ternary) inside a for statement

Tags: c++

it's just a question of logical, I tried to search about this but I found nothing. It might be nonsense, but I want to understand better why this doesn't work.

If I do like this:

```
int start = 5;
int times = (start >= 5) ? 10 : 15;

for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Times: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

It works.

But when I try like this, doesn't:

```
int start = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < ((start >= 5) ? 10 : 15); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Times: " << i << std::endl;
}
```

What is the difference and why this doesn't work? - As I said, don't judge me, it might be nonsense, but I don't know what happen.

You can make it work, or is there another better structure for my case?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is `start` intentionally different between the two code snaps? Also, if you say something "doesn't work", always be specific - what **exactly** doesn't work? compile error? wrong behavior?

Comment: start takes a different value in the second. Shouldn't you be testing with the same values? Also, how doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work. Describe what happens.

Comment: I changed the second `start`, just to test. What happen is that the second case is never called, just the first one. The `10`.

Comment: "why this doesn't work?" -- what does it mean?

Comment: Are you trying with compiler optimization disabled? May the issue related to a compiler bug if updates are not installed.

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri - What you mean? I'm compiling using that: `g++ -O2 -std=c++11 ...`

Comment: The code you posted would work. If you have something that doesn't work, post a compilable example, and the actual and expected output.

Comment: I don't know GCC's compiler switches... in Visual Studio O2 means full optimizations and Od disable all. EDIT: Saw docs. O0 disabled all.

Comment: So, with optimizations disabled did work but when enabled fails?

Answer (score 2):

Your second version works fine in Visual Studio. Here is the output I got in my console window:

```
Times: 0
Times: 1
Times: 2
Times: 3
Times: 4
Times: 5
Times: 6
Times: 7
Times: 8
Times: 9
Times: 10
Times: 11
Times: 12
Times: 13
Times: 14
```